# What is the best way from the following to get the error in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

On Exceptions, what is the best way from the following to get the error in MVC?

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Exception ex0 = this.Context.Error;
        Exception ex1 = httpContext.Error;
        Exception ex2 = Server.GetLastError();
}
```

They return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Server.GetLastError() should be used in Application_Error() in global.asax

Comment: What about the other two ways?